# Angular get clicked word in a text

Tags: angular, string, text, click, selection

In Angular, how can I get the word that has just been clicked or double clicked by the user ?

What I want to do is this : the user double click a word in a text then the text is highlighted.

Text: "This is just some text"

> the user clicks on the word "just" > I get it in the TS.

I have googled it but the only info I found are 10 years old threads in Angular JS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by getting the selected word from text and replacing it with HTML  tag to highlight it.

Here is the working example -

```
export class AppComponent {
  text = "Start editing to see some magic happen";
  selectedWord: string;

  highlight(event) {
    this.selectedWord = window.getSelection().toString();
    this.text = this.text.replace(
      this.selectedWord,
      "<mark>" + this.selectedWord + "</mark>"
    );
  }
}
```

In the html file, you need to use innerHTML for text and call highlight() method on doubleclick event like this -

```
<p [innerHTML]="text" (dblclick)="highlight($event)"></p>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hightlight-on-click?file=src/app/app.component.html) is also a stackbiltz working example.

Comment: Waow ! Perfect ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Acoma You are welcome. If it is working for you, can you please accept the answer and give an upvote. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I have a scenario where same words can be repeated so can you suggest me how to handle that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use **hostListner** to monitor dblclick. please check the following

```
@HostListener('document:dblclick', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown(event) {
      let selectedText:any = ''; 

      if (window.getSelection) { 
          selectedText = window.getSelection().toString(); 
      } else if (document.getSelection) { 
          selectedText = document.getSelection().toString(); 
      } 
      console.log(selectedText);
      return; 
  }
```

i think this will help for you